# Windows 7 running on a Virtual Machine on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: system-installation, virtualization, 18.10

Looking to have a virtual machine setup and be able to either install or direct the VM to boot to an install of windows 7, is it possible to do?

Comment: Yes it is possible, I have one right now. Can you clarify what do you mean? I may misinterpret your achivement.

Comment: I want the ability to virtualize windows desktop to run within Ubuntu.

Comment: Where can I find out how to do that?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Install+Windows+7+on+virtualbox+Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing Windows 7 through Virtual machine to run within Ubuntu system is completely possible, I can't see a reason why it wouldn't.

If you unable to do so, it's either a problem with Ubuntu side or VM program side.

[image]

<sub>Windows 7 installation screen on Virtualbox, running from 18.04 64Bit</sub>

1. Get a Windows 7 `.iso` file.
2. Run through the setup installation of new VMs, in Virtualbox I had to set.

   - Virtual Machine names
   - Amount of RAM
   - (Virtual) Hard Disk space
3. Load the `.iso` to your newly created VM.
4. You're all set.

Comment: Thank you for that Emmet. Where can I get a windwos .iso. Do I download VirtualBox from an official website?

Comment: Actually I've found the windows .iso, thank you for the link pretty simple I guess but you clearly detailed steps a easy thing for me to do myself. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @TLable Virtualbox can be downloaded from their official site, or `sudo apt install virtualbox` should suffice, for the `.iso` I downloaded it from adguard site —found on reddit.

Comment: @TLable If you find it helpful, consider accept this answer by clicking grey checkmark to turn into green checkmark ✅. That would help others too when stumble across your post.